# Electret microphone weird offset problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, microphone, offset

Hi I am trying to amplify my output from electrec (analog microphone) with below design. When I used 1uF capacitor it has -300mV offset, so that I changed capacitor to lower value with trial-error applications. With 200pF ı was able to remove offset (it was something like -10 mV). But when I connec it to an opamp it had an offset again from the same point!

To be more clear When I don't connect it to opamp I was getting a nice output from the - leg of the capacitor. When I connect -leg of the capacitor I got an offset around -200 mV from the -leg of the capacitor. Which is really weird I think I couldn't come up with a solution. I am Using LM741

[image: Cİrcuit]

[image: My amplifier]

Comment: Please draw a schematic and also mention which specific opamp you are using and how you are powering it with supply voltages.

Comment: Did it please consider C on both circuit are sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electret microphone has a FET buffer inside of it and has a DC offset. The capacitor blocks the offset, however you need a path for the bias current of the op-amp. Bias current is a current flowing into or out of the op-amp input. The capacitor also blocks that voltage, so it will tend to float up towards one rail or the other rail depending on the op-amp. A resistor to ground is the usual way to provide that path.

The pole formed by the capacitor and the resistor to ground gives you low frequency roll-off. So if you use a 100K resistor to ground and a 0.1uF (100nF) capacitor the response will be -3dB at 16Hz. If your op-amp has a bias current of 100nA then the input offset due to the 100K resistor will be 10mV (the op-amp will have a bit of offset voltage in addition, which may add or subtract from that). If you match the resistances seen at the inputs the total input offset may be less if the input bias currents are well matched, however that's not always necessary or desirable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYW4IY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

The LM741 has a *typical* input bias current of 80nA at room temperature (though it can be as much as 1.5uA under extreme conditions). 80nA * 100K is 8mV. The op-amp has an offset of typically +/-1mV so the typical output offset with your gain of 11 should be less than 100mV at room temperature.

Comment: is this 100nF capacitor at the beginning is a replacement for 1uF or it is connected serial with it ? And why we don't connect more than 100k Ohm resistor if it lowers offset ? like 1MOhm

Comment: Replacement. 1M will increase the offset because bias current x resistance. If you use an op-amp with lower input bias current you can use a higher resistance and lower the capacitor value for the same low frequency cutoff and offset.

Comment: So why not using less than 100K ? Btw thanks I will try this next week and select yours as true answer if it works

Comment: You can, and it might be appropriate. You'll need a proportionally larger value for the capacitor and it will load the microphone, but not much down to 10K or so.

Comment: To be honest I didn't understan that boundaries and calculations

Comment: Hey it really removed offset but it converted the microphone output to something like triangular wave (not exactly it was like combining sinusoidal and triangular)